# Mouse button hotkeys only work once, not continual

Tags: mouseevent, autohotkey, keydown, hotkeys

I need to make an AutoHotkey script that performs some action when and while the mouse button is pressed, then finishes when the mouse button is released.

For (a very simplified) example:

```
LButton::
  MouseGetPos x,y
  MsgBox %x%-%y%
LButton Up::MsgBox Foobar
```

Replacing the <kbd>LButton</kbd> with a keyboard key (e.g., <kbd>LWin</kbd>) makes it work correctly and moving the mouse cursor updates as expected while the key is held down, but using the mouse button only performs the <kbd>LButton</kbd> action one time. I need the hotkey action to continue occurring until the button is no longer being held.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bunch of query-term tweaking, I found [a page](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/64576-the-definitive-autofire-thread/) that gives sample scripts for *autofire*.

I wasn’t sure that was what I wanted (even though it made sense) because as I said, the sample script already works just fine for keys, but I gave it a shot anyway. I tweaked the sample a bit and now it works as desired. (Actually, it is very similar to a solution I had already been using, but now it absorbs the button event, which solves the underlying problem that I led me to trying the aforementioned script.)

Hopefully I picked good keywords in this post so that anyone else who finds themselves in the same situation can find the/a solution faster than I did.

```
#SingleInstance,force
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

LButton::
 While GetKeyState("LButton","p") {
    MouseGetPos x,y
    Tooltip %x%/%y%
    Sleep 75
 }
return

LButton Up::
    Tooltip Foobar
return
```